# admin-ajax.php returning 0

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm currently working on a WordPress contact form, which is created as a plugin. I need the form after submit to send an email without reloading the page. When it reloads everything is ok. The problem is when submit button is pressed and e.preventDefault() is active the browser shows me **500 (Internal Server Error)** with **admin-ajax.php = 0**

P.S The post is edited

```
     <?php
        add_action( 'admin_footer', 'html_form_code' ); // Write our JS below here
        //
        function html_form_code() {
        ?>
        <form action="<?php esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] )?>" method="post" class="contact-form" id="contact-form" >
            <div class=header-contact>
                <p><h2>Contact Form</h2></p>
                <hr>
            </div>
            <div class=input-containers>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="cf-name" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+" value="" size="40" placeholder="Име и фамилия"/>
            </div>
            <div class=input-containers>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="cf-email" value="" size="40" placeholder="Поща"/>
            </div>
            <div class=input-containers>
                <input type="text" id="subject" name="cf-subject" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" value="" size="40" placeholder="Относно"/>
            </div>
            <div class=input-containers>
                <textarea rows="10" id="message" cols="35" name="cf-message" placeholder="Текст"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class=input-containers>
                <input type="submit" name="cf-submitted" value="Send" id="submitForm">
            </div>
            <p id="verify" style="display:none;">Your message has been sent.<br /><br /></p> 
        </form>
        <script>
    jQuery('#contact-form').submit(function(e){

         e.preventDefault();
         var name =  jQuery('#name').val();
         var email =  jQuery('#email').val();
         var subject =  jQuery('#subject').val();
         var message =  jQuery('#message').val();
                  jQuery.ajax({
                   url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                   type: "POST",
                   data:{ 
                      action: 'send_email', 
                      name: name,
                      email: email,
                      subject: subject,
                      message: message,
                        },
                   success:function(res){
            alert("Email Sent.");
            }
         }); 
        });
    </script>
        <?php
        }
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_send_email', 'deliver_mail' );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_send_email', 'deliver_mail' );

        function deliver_mail() {
            require_once "wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php";
            if (isset($_POST["cf-submitted"])) {

                // sanitize form values
                $name    = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-name"] );
                $email   = sanitize_email( $_POST["cf-email"] );
                $subject = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-subject"] );
                $message = esc_textarea( $_POST["cf-message"] );

                // get the blog administrator's email address

                //$to = "email@gmx.com";
                $headers = "From: $name <$email>" . "\r\n";

                // Localhost
                $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
                $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
                $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

                $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
                $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
                $mail->Host = "mail.gmx.com";      // sets GMX as the SMTP server for example: mail.gmx.com
                $mail->Port = 465;                 // set the SMTP port for the GMX server


                $mail->Username = $email;
                $mail->Password = 'pass';

                $mail->SetFrom($email, $name);
                $mail->AddAddress($email);

                $mail->Subject = $subject;
                $mail->MsgHTML($message);

                $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8";
                $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit";

                try {
                    $mail->send();
                    $msg = "An email has been sent for verfication.";
                    $msgType = "success";

                    wp_safe_redirect( home_url(), 302 );
                    exit();

                } catch (Exception $ex) {
                    $msg = $ex->getMessage();
                    $msgType = "warning"; 

                    wp_safe_redirect( home_url(), 302 );
                    exit();
                }  

        add_action( 'init', function() {
            if ( ! empty( $_POST['form_submitted'] ) ) {
                deliver_mail();        
            }
        });

        function cf_shortcode() {
            ob_start();
            //deliver_mail();
            html_form_code();

            //ob_end_flush(); 
            return ob_get_clean();
        }
        add_shortcode( 'contact_form_second', 'cf_shortcode' );
```

Comment: try "return false;" after your ajax call definition in submit action.

Comment: You aren't posting any data and you need to send it to proper wordpress ajax end point that is set up to handle the processing

Comment: Your `$.ajax` doesn't sent anything along. You need to add the form data: `data: $('#contact-form').serialize();`

Comment: The problem is not in the sending data. With or without it it is the same. P.S I edited the code.

Comment: You got a syntax error there: `data: $('#contact-form').serialize();` - change the `;` to `,` (i.e. comma). *The problem is not in the sending data.* - actually yes, it is *one of* the problems. *With or without it it is the same.* - **with it**, you still need to change the `url` to `admin-ajax.php`, and also send the proper 'action', which in your case is `my_action`. So try `url: "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=my_action' ); ?>",`

Comment: Why "my_action"? This url doesn't work.

Comment: @j-domino Because the 'action' name is `my_action` as in `wp_ajax_my_action` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the data you want to send, try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 
  $('#contact-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //e.stopPropagation();
    const email=$('#email').val()
    const name=$('#name').val()
    const subject=$('#subject').val()
    const message=$('#message').val()
    const data={
       'name':name,
       'email':email,
       'subject':subject,
       'message':message
    }
    
    $.ajax({
       type: 'post',
       url: '/',
       data:{...data},
       success: function () {
          //alert(formData);
          $('#verify').show();
          $('#verify').fadeIn().html("gff");

          setTimeout(function() {
             $('#verify').fadeOut("slow");
          }, 5000 );
          
          $(".contact-form")[0].reset();
       },
       error: function() {
          alert('Error!');
       }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: May be the problem is in the init function  - deliver_mail() and its place in the code.